# Evaluate a single string mathematicaly in bash

Tags: bash

With `awk` I filtered a file and saved into a variable `foo`. For example, `echo $foo` returns `1700 / 2340`.

**edit:** I know how to filter again and **save each number into a variable** so some math could be done with the 2 variables.

But I'd like to know if it is **possible to evaluate the expression easily**, I mean, some `command` to produce `0,726495726` (the result of the division `1700 / 2340`), e.g., `command $foo` outputs `0,726495726`.

Comment: `echo "scale=2; $foo" | bc -l` will do it.

Comment: @bfontaine, I don't think it is duplicated, because I would like to avoid using two variables. I know how to divide. I'd like to *recognize that the string is a division of two numbers and return the evaluated value*.

Comment: @codeforester, exactly. Thanks so much. If you wish, please, post as answer.

Comment: Guys, I'm checking the possible answers cited as duplicated but I think it is different approach. I don't have 2 variables. I have a single one with such expression `3 / 4`. I didn't find the answer given by @codeforester on those posts.

Comment: In bash it would be a dangerous thing to evaluate, as it could contain commands, but ˋeval “r=\$\[$foo\]“ should do.